# NullPointerException при работе с Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

Я пытаюсь получить список фильмов через API. Выдает ошибку `NullPointerException`.

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("movie/upcoming")
    Call<MoviesResponse> getUpcomingMovies(@Query("api_key") String apiKey);

    @GET("movie/{id}")
    Call<MoviesResponse> getMovieDetails(@Path("id") int id, @Query("api_key") String apiKey);
}

public class ApiClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Адаптер:

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MovieViewHolder> {
    private List<Movie> movies;
    private int rowLayout;
    private Context context;

    public class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        LinearLayout moviesLayout;
        TextView movieTitle;
        TextView data;
        TextView movieDescription;

        public MovieViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            moviesLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movies_layout);
            movieTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            data = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
            movieDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);

        }
    }

    public MoviesAdapter(List<Movie> movies, int rowLayout, Context context) {
        this.movies = movies;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MoviesAdapter.MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
        return new MovieViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MovieViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.movieTitle.setText(movies.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.data.setText(movies.get(position).getReleaseDate());
        holder.movieDescription.setText(movies.get(position).getOverview());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return movies.size();
    }
}
```

Активити:

```
public class RetrofitActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = RetrofitActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private final static String API_KEY = "56786b8540dfe459a1f9a73ff088490e ";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrofit);

        if (API_KEY.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please obtain your API KEY from themoviedb.org first!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<MoviesResponse> call = apiService.getUpcomingMovies(API_KEY);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<MoviesResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MoviesResponse> call, Response<MoviesResponse> response) {
                int statusCode = response.code();
                List<Movie> movies = response.body().getResults();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter
                        (movies, R.layout.list_item_movie, getApplicationContext()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MoviesResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
e: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.alex.calculator, PID: 586
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.example.alex.calculator.main.Retrofit.model.MoviesResponse.getResults()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.alex.calculator.main.Retrofit.activity.RetrofitActivity$1.onResponse(RetrofitActivity.java:49)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Comment: @АлександрКириллов, код и стектрейс приложите к вопросу

Comment: `body` у вас null. Скорее всего сервер вернул какую-то ошибку. Вы её игнорируете и пытаетесь прочитать `body`, которого нет. Проверьте `response.code();`. При успехе он должен быть 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была в `api`. Лишний пробел:

```
private final static String API_KEY = "56786b8540dfe459a1f9a73ff088490e "
```

Comment: укажите, где именно

Comment: private final static String API_KEY = "56786b8540dfe459a1f9a73ff088490e ";